# What was this book about a labyrinth?

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a book about a man who could smell emotion, and lived in a labyrinth filled with traps.

A team goes into the labyrinth either to get him, or for archeological reasons, and have to contend with the multitude of traps.

I think it may have been called *Labyrinth*, but without an author, I've no hope of finding this one.

Comment: If you got the title right, search for *Labyrinth* as a fiction title on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi).

Comment: How can it be a duplicate of a question asked 3 years later?

Comment: related meta discussion: [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4749/98028)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds very much like [The Man in the Maze](http://sciencefictionruminations.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/book-review-the-man-in-the-maze-robert-silverberg-1969/) (1969), by Robert Silverberg.